# How can I make Citrix Workspace Client session span multiple monitors

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, citrix

So I'm able to login to my VDI using Citrix Workspace on Ubuntu 20.04.  I never had an issue in this regard.  However, when I try to login and make it so my session spans multiple monitors, I'm never able to make this work. Searching online, I've seen documentation that indicates one is supposed to run the following command in the terminal:
`/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfica -span h`

However, when I do that, I see a window pop saying 'Cannot find an ICA file or appserv.ini entry'

Does anyone know how to get around/resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I'm working on similar issues now and thought it might be helpful. In this case wfica is the program that runs the .ica file that you download from the web interface. The error message indicates that it cannot find the file it is supposed to run. So you need to provide the path to the downloaded file after wfica and before the modifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Can you elaborate a bit more when you say, "you  need to provide the path to the downloaded file after wfica and before the modifiers."  Can you share what you did exactly?

Comment: So from the Citrix storefront website after logging in, I download a .ica file to connect. Then, assuming you are in the same folder as the file named "test.ica", you would run this command: /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfica -file test.ica -span h

Comment: I should also mention that this doesn't actually make the dual monitors work for me, for whatever reason. I've also tried editing the configuration files as mentioned in various places, to no avail. What I finally did to get it to "work" is to open the downloaded .ica file and set the TWIMode parameter to "Off" instead of "On", then run it. That opens the rmd in a resizable window, which I can spread accross both monitors. Not exactly what dual monitors is supposed to be, and very hacky, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

## Citrix Workspace app 2207 for Linux

In 2022 you can [download](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/) the latest version of the Citrix client software start your session, move the window so that it covers two monitors and click the button to got full screen. I have 3 monitors connected and it will cover 2 of them. Since all of them are 4k monitors I hit a limitation to span across all 3. If I stretch the window beyond the second screen I get it to cover a small strip of the third until it resets its size to one monitor.

On a Mac this is also the recommended way as it seems. I got it to work with 3 monitors over there, but the Mac client at the moment only supports 1080p on external monitors. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73500366/2010467).